# Converting String to String of Hex and vice-versa in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, hex, ascii

I need to convert a String of totally random characters in something i can read back!
My idea is:

Example String: hi

```
h (Ascii) -> 68 (hex) 
i (Ascii) -> 69 (hex)
```

So converting `hi` i must have `6869`

My value is now in `Base64` (i got it with a `Convert.ToBase64String()`), is this "ascii to hex" conversion correct? In base64 i have value like "4kIw0ueWC/+c=" but i need **characters** only, special characters can mess my system

The vb.net  Convert can only translate to base64 string :(

edit: This is my final solution:
i got the base64 string inside my `enc` variable and converted it first in ASCII then in corrispondent Hex using:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(enc)
Dim hex As String = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", String.Empty)
```

After that i reversed this with:

```
Dim b((input.Length \ 2) - 1) As Byte
For i As Int32 = 0 To b.GetUpperBound(0)
     b(i) = Byte.Parse(input.Substring(i * 2, 2), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
Next i
Dim enc As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
result = enc.GetString(b)
```

After all this i got back my base64string and converted one last time with `Convert.FromBase64String(result)`

Done! Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Base64 has got nothing to do with hexadecimal representation.

Comment: yes i know, sorry if the post looks like i have confusion on it, i'm still learning english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get `Byte()` from your `base64` string:

```
Dim data = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString)
```

Then use [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx):

```
String hex = BitConverter.ToString(data)
```

Comment: That doesn’t convert *characters*, it converts bytes. I think OP doesn’t actually want Base64 encoding at all.

Comment: i now got something like "90-8C-34-B9-E5-82-FF-E7", and it's ok for me! I'll just remove any "-" character and do the reverse function to made this work! Thank you!